# Quick Time Series Question

Tags: time-series

I have two time series which are somewhat correlated, and I am tasked with discovering if one of the time series "leads" the other.  I am guessing this means that, if one time series moves in a certain way, the other time series will move that way, but perhaps a bit slower, or "lagged."

I have extensive knowledge of mathematics and statistics, but I have never worked with time series before.  Is there a test that is for this problem?  What can I do here?

Perhaps this question is better suited for CrossValidated, but this site is more popular, and this is math nonetheless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may have been beneficial to get clarification on what was precisely meant by *"leads" the other*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply Granger Causality test. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality).